# Mapbox GL JS - Stacking/Layering Image overlays on each other

Tags: mapbox, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I am wanting to layer multiple image overlays over each other on a map (minimum will be 3, maximum 10). These are weather radar images with each image being a higher elevation in the storm. I have attached a screenshot. Just imagine several layers over that image in the same spot.

I am hoping there's an easy image style like "HeightAboveGround" or something like that that will let me do this.

If this is possible, is there also a way to tilt/rotate image overlays? This would be such a nice feature in the map.

[image: First layer of composite]

Answer (score 1):

> I am wanting to layer multiple image overlays over each other...with each image being a higher elevation in the storm.

There is no way to render image overlays at any height other than zero.

> If this is possible, is there also a way to tilt/rotate image overlays?

If by "tilt", you mean, along an axis parallel to the ground, such that one end of the image is higher than the other, then there's no way to do that.

If, by "rotate" you mean, along an axis perpendicular to the ground, so that the image no longer aligns with north, then there's no way to do that either.

Sorry this couldn't be more helpful. :) If 3D is important to your application, you might want to consider using a true 3D library (as opposed to 2.5D) such as Cesium.